# How so I step through the code in an application that uses Unity?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0, unity-container

I don't want to step through the Unity source code.

I am looking at the StopLight sample that comes with Unity.  I wanted to step through the code in the application so that I can figure out what's going on but if I put a breakpoint on the closing bracket of the StopLightForm constructor and then try and step I just get 'No Source Available ... blah, blah, blah'.

How do I just step through the code in the sample app?

Comment: Double check that Just My Code is enabled in Tools-> Options --> Debugging --> General

Comment: @Mark Hall - I tried this, doesn't make any difference.